# Cordova: links to javascript files located in local resource Not allowed

Tags: cordova, security, local, whitelist, cordova-5.0.0

**The Status:**

I have some java script files I download from my server and save them in the device storage, and want to link them to my `index.html` just like this:

```
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    src="file:///data/data/<app_id>/files/path/to/my-script.js/">
</script>
```

and the same for `CSS`.

**This the error:**

```
Not allowed to load local resource:
file:///data/data/<app_id>/files/path/to/style.css
```

NOTE: this was allowed in the previous versions of cordova, but since I updated to cordova 5, I forced to install the plugin whitelist and then this permission error appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by creating an embed tiny web server into Cordova with this plugin [CorHttpd Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd)

then simply refer to the stylesheet by as following:

```
<link src="http://localhost:8080/css/file.css">
```

and you can refer to JS file by the following:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/js/script.js" ><script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to achieve this on Android. If thats correct I suppose you can use the following to resolve any file on the external file system:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, cbSuccess, cbFail);



path - {string} a cordova path with scheme: 
                     'cdvfile://localhost/<file-system-name>/<path-to-file>' 
                 Examples: 'cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/path/to/global/file'
                           'cdvfile://localhost/cache/onlyVisibleToTheApp.txt'
cbSuccess - {function} a callback method that receives a DirectoryEntry object.

cbFail - {Function} a callback method that receives a FileError object.
```

This though requires some configuration.

config.xml

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="sdcard,cache" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Used the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868089/how-to-access-external-storage-with-cordova-file-file-system-roots-plugins) for instance.

Comment: thanks George, but does this help my `android_asset/www/index.html` to include CSS file from the sd card?
In fact I just want to make some files updateable from my server to be included later in my index.html