# How to read/write external storage file android with cordova (resolveLocalFileSystemURL)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, external

I'm newbie ionic 1.I using plugin cordova.file

How to read/write external storage (memory flash) file android with cordova (resolveLocalFileSystemURL)

Thanks

Comment: Small search and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23288548/8198240) what I got.

Comment: @Mr. k https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations